# Asp.Net MVC Client Side Validation Indicator that Allows Form Submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I have an asp.net MVC application that needs to show client side validation but still allow the form to be posted back to the server.  For example, I want the person completing the form to be able to see a dynamic required field asterisk when filling in data.  However when the user goes to "save" the form, I still want the data to save in the database.

On my website, I have a view model which contains the required field attributes the only problem is when I enable client side validation in MVC it prevents the form from submitting.

Is there an easy way to override this with JavaScript to allow the form to post data?

Comment: Well, why do you want to make a field Required if you can save it without any value?

Comment: The user can save the application and then come back and return to fill it out at a later time.  In order to submit the application, all required fields must be present.